# Double waiting condition in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I can't add a double condition for waiting in selenium.
I am doing automation and I want to set a double waiting condition in selenium for a full file upload to the server.

My goal is to wait until the file is uploaded to the site server. I want to use EC.text_to_be_present_in_element 2 times so that the waiting condition is checked both by file name and by type. That is, I will check if there is a file with the same name and type on the site.

```
def wait_send_files(file_name, file_type):
    xpath_file_name = 'some_xpath'
    xpath_file_type = 'some_xpath_2'
    WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=90).until(EC.and_(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_file_name), file_name),
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_file_type), file_type)
    ))

for file in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file)
    file_input.send_keys(file_path)

    if file.startswith('some_text') or file.startswith('some_text'):
        if file.endswith('pdf'):
            file_name = 'some_text1'
            file_type = 'pdf'
            wait_send_files(file_name, file_type)
        elif file.endswith('xls'):
            file_name = 'some_text2'
            file_type = 'xls'
            wait_send_files(file_name, file_type)
```

Unfortunately, I can't use 'presence_of_element_located' because the site elements don't disappear, also I can't use "element_to_be_clickable" since the site elements really become non-clickable at the time of loading, but my waiting doesn't work, that is, the script waits until it throws a timeoutexception exception.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=90).until(EC.and_(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_file_name), file_name),
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_file_type), file_type)
```

This part of the code was suggested to me by chatgpt, but my interpreter says about the error in this fragment "EC.and_("
Is there an alternative way to set a double condition for waiting in selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Just separate to 2 different conditions and wait for each one of them:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=90).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,
xpath_file_name), file_name))
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=90).until(    
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,
xpath_file_type), file_type))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both yours and the other person's method did not help. I also made an expectation in the form of such a function: 
def wait_send_files(file_upload_sieb):
    xpath_file_name = 'some_xpath'
    file_name_sieb = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_file_name).text
    print(file_name_sieb)
    print(file_upload_sieb)

    while True:
        if file_name_sieb != file_upload_sieb:
            time.sleep(10)
        elif file_name_sieb == file_upload_sieb:
            break
But waiting still doesn't work, even though the code is logically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation (https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) the "and_" condition does not exist.
You should probably use EC.all_of like:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=90).until(EC.all_of(
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_file_name), file_name),
    EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, xpath_file_type), file_type)
))
```